# Excel: Duplicated PlotOrder for two Series in a Chart

Tags: excel, charts, series

I have a `ChartObject`, with 10 `Series`. I have two `Series` with `.PlotOrder` = 1, and two other with `.PlotOrder` = 2. Therefore, the `.PlotOrder` of the last `Series` is 8. Can this be explained? I expected `.PlotOrder` to span from 1 to `.Count`.

Proof of what I have is that, during execution of a `Sub`, I get in `cho` a reference to the `ChartObject` in question. Then, in the immediate window:

```
? cho.Chart.SeriesCollection(cho.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count).PlotOrder
 8

? cho.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
 10
```

Comment: `Plot Order` is defined as _the plot order for the selected series within the **chart group**._ and `chart group` is _a collection of series with the **same chart type**._  Is it possible you have several different chart types within your set of series?

Comment: Geez, I've been working on charts all these years, and thought of myself as an expert, and I didn't know this about plotorder. I was going to refute your comment, but then decided to check in case it changed in 2013. I tested all the way back to 2003, and I was wrong on all counts.

Comment: @Jon, please see the official site on [Series.PlotOrder Property (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838961.aspx): "Returns or sets the plot order for the selected series within the chart group. Read/write Long." This time they gave appropriate info (but often we need SE to get there).

Comment: @Jon you might be interested in my EDIT of [Excel: In which ways can one create ChartGroups?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841561/excel-in-which-ways-can-one-create-chartgroups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply to @chrisneilsen, but it is too long for adding as a comment.

The reply is partially correct (I summarize here what I found):

1. The repeated `PlotOrder`s are due to the `Chart` having more than one `ChartGroup`
2. I do not have `Series` with different format (they have different `ChartType`s, but all with format `XYScatter`).

   The grouping is not automatically done by `ChartType`, with the `ChartType`s of my case, so this does not seem to be the cause for having more than one `ChartGroup`. It may have been automatic (and it probably was), but based on other criteria.

Details:

Working with another chart that presents the same situation (all `Series` with format `XYScatter`), I have executed a Sub to dump info on all `ChartGroups` and all the `Series` in the chart. Indented once it dumps `ChartGroups`, and indented twice it dumps `Series` in each `ChartGroup`.

```
ChartObject 'Chart 36', no. series: 6
* ChartGroup, .Index: 1, no. series: 2
** plot order: 1, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 36', chart type: 73, no. points: 17
** plot order: 2, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 36', chart type: -4169, no. points: 17
* ChartGroup, .Index: 2, no. series: 4
** plot order: 1, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 36', chart type: 75, no. points: 2
** plot order: 2, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 36', chart type: -4169, no. points: 24
** plot order: 3, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 36', chart type: 75, no. points: 33
** plot order: 4, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 36', chart type: -4169, no. points: 5
```

Therefore, the repeated `PlotOrder`s are due to the `Chart` having more than one `ChartGroup` (as correctly guessed by @chrisnielsen).

On the other hand, `ChartGroup`s do not group series by `ChartType` (as stated by @chrisnielsen) as seen in the dump. Moreover, I do not know how were the `ChartGroup`s created and the `Series` included in each `ChartGroup` (I never did this intentionally).

And to test whether the grouping may have been done automatically, I created another `Chart` which has Series with the same `ChartType`s as the one above, and they all belong to a single `ChartGroup`, as shown in the dump

```
ChartObject 'Chart 1', no. series: 6
* ChartGroup, .Index: 1, no. series: 6
** plot order: 1, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 1', chart type: 73, no. points: 17
** plot order: 2, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 1', chart type: -4169, no. points: 17
** plot order: 3, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 1', chart type: 75, no. points: 2
** plot order: 4, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 1', chart type: -4169, no. points: 24
** plot order: 5, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 1', chart type: 75, no. points: 33
** plot order: 6, type: -4169, chart: 'Chart 1', chart type: -4169, no. points: 5
```

So the grouping is not automatically done by `ChartType`, with the `ChartType`s of my case. It may have been automatic (and it probably was), but based on other criteria.

The official site is not very helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa173251%28v=office.11%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa173240%28v=office.11%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195778%28v=office.11%29.aspx

This sparks another question, which I posted in

[Excel: In which ways can one create ChartGroups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841561/excel-in-which-ways-can-one-create-chartgroups)

Comment: Chart Groups group series by class of chart type, on a given axis. So all XY Scatter series are in the same chart group, unless some are on the primary axis and others on the secondary axis.

Comment: @JonPeltier - This is a good answer for the linked question. I wouldn't be sure if this is my case, but it is useful.